# Can I have fontend(pages) together with a backend in a monolithic or microservices?

Tags: microservices, monolithic

I think these are conceptual questions, but for example, can we have a monolithic application that renders the pages and assembles the views (back and front together) or a monolith that is an api for a frontend application? And in the case of microservices, we can have microservices that render the pages or will always be APIs for consumption by a frontend application (or any other)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe!

Microservices usually means dividing your system into business contexts as opposed to software implementations.

So if the business context is, for example, the user experience, it makes sense that you put all of it in one place. User experience is mostly implemented in a webclient or mobile app layer, but can be heavily affected by a backend layer that serves those clients. In this case, bundling them together within the same code base and deployment cadence makes a lot of sense.

This "experience" microservice should have clear boundaries, though. Persisting things in a database is not part of the experience as a simple example.